# $f'$ decreasing, is $f'$ continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

Suppose $f:(0,\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb R$ is positive and differentiable and $f'$ is decreasing to $0$.

Is $f'$ continuous?

I know that $f'$ has to have intermediate value property so it can not have any discontinuous jumps, but is the assumption that $f'$ is decreasing sufficient for the continuity?

Proof or counterexample would be great

Comment: Yes, it is sufficient. A monotonic functikn can only have jump discontinuities, and by the theorem you've stated, since $f '$ has to satisfy the intermediate value property, $f' $ can't have a jump discontinuity.

Comment: It seems that your question should be generalized: You do not need $f$ positive and $f'$ decreasing to $0$. It suffices to consider $f$ such that $f'$ is monotonic.